# Loading attribtues from an element within an element

Tags: c#, xml, foreach, linq-to-xml

so I have this code that should allow me to list all the attributes from an element within an element within another element (elementception?) in an xml file. What I'm trying to do is have it where the first list (`lst_adventure` in my code) loads the first level of elements attributes (the name attributes). Upon selecting one of said elements, list 2 (`lst_adventures` with an s) loads the next level of elements in the previously selected element. After selecting a second level element, list 3 (`lst_senario`) loads up the scenario elements from within the previous element that's within the previous element. It's kinda confusing trying to explain. But hwat's happinging right now is it'll load both the first and second elements perfectly but the 3rd list remains empty. Any help would be great.

```
    string selectedItem = lst_Adventure.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string selectedAdventure = lst_Adventures.SelectedItem.ToString();

    XDocument doc = new XDocument();

    doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\WpfApplication1\\WpfApplication1\\Adventures.xml");

    XElement selectedElement = doc.Descendants().Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == selectedItem).FirstOrDefault();
    XElement selectedAdventures = selectedElement.Descendants().Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == selectedItem).FirstOrDefault();

    if (selectedAdventures != null)
    {
        foreach (var docs in selectedAdventures.Elements("senario"))
        {
            string AdventuresPathName = docs.Attribute("Name").Value;
            lst_Adventures.Items.Add(AdventuresPathName);
        }
    }
```

The xml file I'm using is this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<adventures>
  <adventure_path Name ="Adventure Path 1">
    <adventure Name ="Adventure 1">
      <senario Name ="Senario 1"/>
      <senario Name ="Senario 2"/>
    </adventure>
    <adventure Name="Addventure 2">
      <senario Name ="Senario 3"/>
    </adventure>
  </adventure_path>
  <adventure_path Name ="Adventure Path 2">
    <adventure Name ="Adventure 3">
      <senario Name ="Senario 4"/>
      <senario Name ="Senario 5"/>
    </adventure>
  </adventure_path>
</adventures>
```

So the code should add each scenario name attribute to lst_scenario within the selected item in lst_adventure and lst_adventures. So far it doesn't.

Comment: You should make your question more generic: remove everything that is not important (like the UI controls usage) and state exactly what inputs you have and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok Is that any better?

Answer (score 0):

Following works just fine:

```
string selectedItem = "Adventure Path 1";
string selectedAdventure = "Adventure 1";

var doc = XDocument.Load("Input.txt");

var selectedElement = doc.Root
                         .Elements("adventure_path")
                         .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == selectedItem)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
var selectedAdventures = selectedElement.Elements("adventure")
                                        .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == selectedAdventure)
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

var items = new List<string>();

if (selectedAdventures != null)
{
    foreach (var docs in selectedAdventures.Elements("senario"))
    {
        string AdventuresPathName = docs.Attribute("Name").Value;
        items.Add(AdventuresPathName);
    }
}
```

You're comparing `Name` attribute value to the same `selectedItem` variable value twice. I've also changed `Descendants` calls to proper `Root`/`Elements()` calls, because you shouldn't use `Descendants` unless you're data is tree-like. And as far as I can see, yours is not.

You can do the same in single query:

```
var items = doc.Root
               .Elements(selectedItem)
               .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == selectedItem)
               .Elements(selectedAdventure)
               .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name") == selectedAdventure)
               .Elements("senario")
               .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name"))
               .ToList();
```

`items` will be `List<string>` with all scenarios under proper XML document part.